# As a System Administrator, can I view a history of all Flow Interviews?

Tags: administration, visual-workflow, activityhistory

Not finding an answer to this in the Salesforce docs...

I want to look at historical use of a Flow.  Not *just* failures (I know that emails are sent when a Flow fails). I would like to see all outcomes of all Interviews - Who ran it, the result, the time of the interview, etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: where you want to view? you can view in debug log

Comment: I was thinking a view similar to the data operations "Jobs"... presentable through the admin interface.

Comment: @ensminger were you able to find a solution / workaround?